# @Entity classes are not mapped without <class> attribute in persistence.xml in JBOSS EAP 7 application

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, ejb, jboss-eap-7

I am trying to Migrate from Weblogic to jboss EAP 7.2 , My project is using EJB3-persistence , @Entity classes are not recognized if  attribute is not given in persistence.xml. When i try to do em.createQuery Entityclass not mapped issue occured. Is it Mandatory in jboss eap 7 to include class attribute?

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import org.apache.commons.lang.builder.EqualsBuilder;
import org.apache.commons.lang.builder.HashCodeBuilder;
import org.apache.commons.lang.builder.ToStringBuilder;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Cache;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CacheConcurrencyStrategy;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Fetch;
import org.hibernate.annotations.FetchMode;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Cache(usage=CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
@Table(name="user_det")
public class UserDet implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


Dao IMpl

        QRY = "from UserDet u";
        try {
            Query q;
            q = entityManager.createQuery(QRY);
```

Persistence.xml

```
<persistence-unit name="xxx" transaction-type="JTA">
<provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider> 
    <jta-data-source>xxxx</jta-data-source>


    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.query.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.hql.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory" />
        <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.JBossTransactionManagerLookup"/>

        <!-- 2nd level cache -->
            <!--
        <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.SingletonEhCacheProvider" />
        <property name="net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName" value="/ehcache.xml" />
    -->
        <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider" />
        <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_configuration_file_resource_path" value="/ehcache.xml"/>



        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true"/>
        <!-- <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true"/>-->
        <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics" value="true" />

        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_structured_entries" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.session_factory_name" value="SessionFactory"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

UserDet not mapped exception thrown , is it mandatory to add class attribute in persistence.xml?

Comment: What happens if you add `<excludeUnlistedClasses>false</excludeUnlistedClasses>`?

Comment: Could you add the stack trace? Adding entities to the `persistence.xml` is not required.

Comment: @crizzis - Same error occurred , Exception Message:

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins - Please find the stacktrace
org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: UserDet is not mapped [from UserDet UserDet ]
Exception Cause: org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: UserDet is not mapped [from UserDet UserDet ]
Exception Trace: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: UserDet is not mapped [from UserDet UserDet ]